# Using Logical Operators On Integers

Tags: c, logical-operators

I saw lately a thread on this site about using logical operators on integers in C. However, I didn't really understand how this worked so here I provide two examples and I hope someone can provide a detailed explanation for them:

1. `int result = 1000 & 255`
2. `int result = 1000 || 255`

Comment: Instead of view the value as decimal, start with binary.  `11 1110 1000 & 1111 1111`.

Comment: In your first example, do you mean `1000 && 255`? `&` is bit operation, while `&&` is boolean operation.

Comment: `int result = 1000 || 255` --> You want a _logical or_ right?

Comment: `1000 || 255 == 1023` while `1000 | 255 == 1000`

Comment: Oh thank you all, fine I got it, it's bitwise & and | as I understand right?

Comment: `1000 || 255` is 1. `1000 | 255` is 1023. `1000 && 255` is 1. `1000 & 255` is 232.

Comment: Please someone provide full answer so I can confirm it and readers can see it.

Comment: Is it worth a full answer? This is pretty basic stuff in C.

Comment: @IanAbbott I know, but it's still a question and others may ask it too, I'm not an amateur in C but still I didn't know this as I never used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimal 1000 is binary 11 1110 1000. Decimal 255 is binary 1111 1111. First, they are converted to `signed int`, which is usually 32 bits wide.

Taking `&` of them sets the bit at all positions where both bits of the operands are set:

```
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1110 1000
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
& ---------------------------------------
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1110 1000
```

This is decimal 232. Taking `|` would have set the bit at all positions where **at least** one bit is set, i.e. would have produced binary 11 1111 1111, which is decimal 1023. Taking `^` would have set the bit at all positions where **exactly** one of the bits is set, i.e.

```
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1110 1000
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
^ ---------------------------------------
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 0001 0111
```

`&&` is not a binary operation. It simply returns 1 if and only if both operands are non-zero. `||` returns 1 if and only if at least one of the operands is non-zero. In other cases, they return 0, respectively.